# Defining an anonymous function using another function but with fewer arguments

Tags: programming

In MATLAB you can use an anonymous function with another function to define a new function with fewer arguments as long you define the excluded argument before, e.g.

```
z=1

f1=@(x,y) f(x,y,z)

x=2

y=3

f1(x,y)
```

Can you do that in Mathematica?

Comment: You'll find that working with anonymous functions is much more flexible and convenient in Mathematica than in MATLAB.  Mathematica is a functional language an anonymous (or named) functions are essential to it.  Look up `Map`, `Fold`, etc. and read this part of the docs: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ExpressionsOverview.html

Answer (score 5):

In Mathematica the equivalent of that would be

```
f1 = f[#1, #2, 1]&
```

The key is using [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html), for which `&` is a short notation.

Note that I inlined the value of `z` here manually, as this is the simplest way to achieve the behaviour of your MATLAB function.

Here's a subtle difference between MATLAB and Mathematica:

MATLAB would capture the value of `z` at the time you define your function, and any subsequent changes to `z` won't affect what the function does.

In contrast to this, Mathematica will simply use the *symbol* `z`, which will in turn evaluate to its global value.  For example:

```
In[1]:= f = # + z &
Out[1]= #1 + z &

In[2]:= f[3]
Out[2]= 3 + z

In[3]:= z = 2
Out[3]= 2

In[4]:= f[3]
Out[4]= 5

In[5]:= z = 3
Out[5]= 3

In[6]:= f[3]
Out[6]= 6
```

Notice that: 1. you can have a symbolic `z` in Mathematica 2. changing the value of the global variable `z` affects what the function does.

If you want to inline the value of a global variable when defining the function (as MATLAB does), use `With`:

```
f = With[{t = z}, #+t&]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f[a_][b_] = a*b
g = f[2]
g[4]

(* 8 *)
```

Comment: I think this is not an analog of the MATLAB code he posted.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I think you're right, your comment is more what the OP is looking for. The idea of defining some function based on an earlier global (or local) is so... yuck.